# How do you pass login failure error after a form in submitted?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having a login component written in reactJS, it is using axios to execute a login end point. If the login fails because of valid reasons, I save the loginerror in state. I then have a div tag in the return part of the JSX, which is supposed to display the error. However this message is not displayed. I understand that the JSX runs before the async call is completed. How do I resolve the issue?

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const { email, password} = this.state;

    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/users/login",
        {         
            email: email,
            password: password        
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status ===200) {
          this.props.handleSuccessfulAuth(response.data);          
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({loginErrors:error}) 
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  }


return(<div>{this.state.state.loginError}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.state.loginError` Should probably be `this.state.loginError`

Furthermore, the error returned by axios is not a simple message but an object.

You'll need to access the property in it if you want to show something. So it would be `this.state.loginError.response.message` or just set the original state to the message

Check this for referrence: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors